# How to share a one mysql connection between multiple threads?

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading

In my application i'm using Mysql.Data connector from dev.mysql.com to write into my mysql database, and i want to maximize performance, so i don't want to open many MySql connections. But eventually when i tried to use one global static connection like so:

```
MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

connect.Open();
StaticData.mysqlConnect = connect;

...


// in my threads
lock (StaticData.mysqlConnect)
{
  foreach (Object param in records)
  {
      using (MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
      {
        command.CommandText = "some request";
        //...                   
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();  
      }
  }
}
```

I got System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException. So my question is: whats the proper way to share one connection between different threads using dev mysql connector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> whats the proper way to share one connection between different threads using dev mysql connector?

Don't.  Have a different connection on each thread.

The connections should be pooled, so when you open up a new connection it's not going to *actually* open up a new connection, it's just going to grab an open connection from the pool.

Because of that there's no reason to have such long lived connections shared between threads.  Just create a new connection for the scope of each logical transaction and let the connection pooling take care of the rest.

Comment: Isn't a connection pool of max size 1 exactly what the OP is looking for? The idea of a pool is to not create a new connection for each transaction, so I am somewhat confused what you are recommending

Comment: @MiserableVariable The `MySqlConnection` type itself *already* maintains a connection pool.  There's no need for him to re-implement a connection pooling mechanism on top of that existing mechanism.

Comment: Oh! I did not know know that about `MySqlConnection`. In that case then as you wrote creating a new connection per transaction is the best approach

Comment: @MiserableVariable Basically all db connections will already do that, or if they don't, they have a config option to enable it.  There's almost never a reason not to do it, which is why most all providers do it by default.

Comment: I do not know about C# but I doubt all JDBC drivers do connection pooling, else why would there be standalone libraries for connection pooling

Comment: @MiserableVariable Not all, but most.  All of the JDBC drivers I've worked with had an option for connection pooling.

Comment: I suppose it is evolution -- connections started by being non-pooled, enter connection pool to avoid frequent open/close, connections learned to pool themselves. Anyway, thanks for patient explanations.