# What will happen to some connection with same connect string?

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading, mysql-connector

Let say i have 4 MySQL connection and a connectString (I leave the connection pooling enabled, i'm using MySQL .NET Connector from MySQL itself)

```
protected internal MySqlConnection connection;
protected internal MySqlConnection cnnct1,cnnct2,cnnct3;
protected internal string connectString = "SERVER=" + addressBox.Text + ";DATABASE=" + dbNameBox.Text + ";UID=" + UserBox.Text + ";PASSWORD=" + PassBox.Text + ";";
```

Then i assign the connections

```
protected internal void connectionMaker()
{
    connection = new MySqlConnection(connectString);
    cnnct1 = new MySqlConnection(connectString);
    cnnct2 = new MySqlConnection(connectString);
    cnnct3 = new MySqlConnection(connectString);
}
```

What i will do with those connections is, since my App is multi-threaded and all thread require to access a single database concurrently at a same time so i think to give each thread different connection, but since they're all accessing to a same DB, even a same table so i think to give each connection same connect string.

for addition each thread will be executing `MySqlReader` with `SELECT` command on same columns on a single table at same time (through Task Parallel Libary), but each of them will read different rows

My questions are, i'm trying to make my code to be as simple and easy as possible, yet is this a safe, good, and correct practice ? if not, is there any simple yet safe approach to do what i'm going to do ?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov i think my question and the one you've marked do have similarity but not same, that question is asking how the questioner can share a connection between threads and the accepted answer suggest to have each thread a separate connection, while my question is asking if is that possible to have different connections with same connect string ? and if not what can i do since those threads need to access a same instance of Database, at a same time.
Actually i made this question after reading that question several times

Answer (score 0):

If the connection string is the same the connections will use the same connection pool.

The best practice is that every thread creates, opens and closes its own connection, the framework will take care of sharing resources when it's possible.

I suggest you to give a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

*Whenever a user calls Open on a connection, the pooler looks for an available connection in the pool. If a pooled connection is available, it returns it to the caller instead of opening a new connection. When the application calls Close on the connection, the pooler returns it to the pooled set of active connections instead of closing it. Once the connection is returned to the pool, it is ready to be reused on the next Open call.*

Comment: Since this references MySQL instead of MSSql there is a similarity to the question answered at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458633/how-to-share-a-one-mysql-connection-between-multiple-threads

Comment: Yes, i've assigned each thread to have it's own connection object (`MySqlConnection`) but since those thread really need to access a same DB even a same table at a really same time, is that possible to create the new connections with same connect string ?

Comment: I think you are worrying to much about it. Just keep the connection string in a single place (the configuration file) and open and close as many connections as you want. The framework will take care of the pooling.